# Trying to login to a ATWS with SUDS error

Tags: python-2.7, suds

Im trying to login to a ATWS service with suds but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AAAA/Documents/Aptana/AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours/Main.py", line 38, in <module>
    handler = ConnectATWS()
  File "/Users/AAAA/Documents/Aptana/AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours/Main.py", line 31, in __init__
    client = Client(self.url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 136, in __init__
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 79, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 95, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 60, in open
    return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 64, in open
    raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

I'm inputting the correct login info, yet I keep getting the Unauthorized error.

This is my code:

```
class ConnectATWS():
    def __init__(self):
        app_config = Init()
        self.username = app_config.data["Username"]
        self.password = app_config.data["Password"]
        self.login_id = app_config.data["LoginID"]
        self.url = app_config.data["AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours_net_autotask_webservices5_ATWS"]

        client = Client(self.url)
        login_res = client.service.Login(self.login_id, self.password)
```

Am I not using SUDS correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication like this

```
    client = Client(self.url)
    login_res = client.service.Login(self.login_id, self.password)
```

will only work if the webservice offers a `Login(user, password)` method which needs to be called to authenticate.

In you case you get a 401 response already when you try to access the service wsdl (when constructing the `Client`), which is an indication that a different authentication method is used, based on the http response probably http basic auth. So the authentication is not done by the service, but on the transport layer.

To use http basic auth with suds is simple, just pass the `username` and `password` keyword arguments to the `Client`:

```
client = Client(self.url, username=self.login_id, password=self.password)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!